# Update huge array of data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've came across the situation, where I need to select huge amount of data (say 100k records, each of them looks somewhat like `ID | {"points":"9","votes":"2","breakdown":"0,0,0,1,1"}`), process it in PHP and then put it back to the DB. Question is about putting it back efficiently. I saw a solution using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, I saw a solution with `UPDATE` using `CASE`. Are there any other solutions? Which would be the most efficient way to update huge array of data?

Answer (score 0):

That's not an "array" as much as it is JSON.  See `json_decode()` and `json_encode()`.

Since you have the ID, simply do

```
UPDATE tbl SET json = ? WHERE ID = ?
```

IODKU is normally for when you *might* be inserting a *new* row.

Since want to update 100K rows, I would walk through the `PRIMARY KEY`, pulling out 1000 rows at a time, change them, then use IODKU to replace all 1000 in a single statement.  (If the JSON is very bulky, shrink the "1000" so that the SQL statement is not more than, say, 5MB.)

`REPLACE` is unlikely to be very fast, since it is `DELETE` + `INSERT`.  Also, it could do a nasty with `AUTO_INCREMENTs.`

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answering. I know how to handle JSON and question is not about that at all. JSON is in the question just to give an idea of what kind of records I'm dealing with. Question is not about getting or handling data but about ***most efficient*** way of putting it back into the DB. So, do you think, 100k separate queries is the most efficient solution here?

Comment: Separate queries have a significant overhead.  So IODKU may be the 'right' way to go.  I updated the answer.